# How to change user-agent and delay time in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy 0.16.4

I have used this code to change the download delay and user-agent:

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22 AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.1"
```

I'm not sure whether this is working, however, I still can't fully crawl all the pages from that site. It always gives me a random scraped items. Sometimes, I got 13, sometimes I got 30, and sometimes I got 52 scraped items.

What could be the issue?

Comment: The issue could be that the site is changing their database or perhaps your internet connections are timing out due to your roommate downloading torrents, but without seeing the log or your code, we can only guess.

Comment: that's not the issue. The issue is there so many data, but I can scrap only some of them. not all. My internet connect is really fast, and I don't have roommate who downloads torrents.

Comment: I was actually trying to say in a funny way: post your code and your log file output.

Comment: @Vicheanak You got any solution for this??

Answer (score 4):

There may be access limits per ip for some websites. There is a great possibility that they may not accumulate the access numbers for different user agents  (like chrome, firefox, ie, or safari etc.), so you may try to use a dynamic user-agent pool to alleviate the heavy accesses.

[Here](http://tangww.com/2013/06/UsingRandomAgent/) is a link for how to "Using random user agent in Scrapy"

Comment: The link is down

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the site blocks you with a captcha, you can print the response.url and see if you're getting a referer, try to set the DOWNLOAD_DELAY to 10, you can set it into the spider and printing the url, if takes 10 seconds to print it's working.